# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 since facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I'm getting really frustrated over this. Every imte i try to export my project I get the error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

I tried a lot of things. I got the newest eclipse. Changed my proguard file.

This error only happened when I added the facebook 3.5.2 SDK to my project. We had in our library the same android-support-v4.jar. I deleted the one in my app and kept the one in the facebook SDK but I still het that error. Can anybody help me it's really frustrating ...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We too faced this error and we found a smart solution for this,
 Steps to resolve this error:

1. Uncheck the "Build Automatically" option in Project menu in eclipse.
2. Do project clean
3. And then, right click on the project name over
   here you will find "Build Project" option
4. Click the "Build
   Project" and now you can start export your project.

I hope it should work to you too.Please try and let me know...

Comment: Wow finally that actually worked. Do I have to build project every time i want to export my project?

Comment: Finally something that worked. I've been pulling my hair out. Have to build the facbook sdk first, then my app.

Answer (score 1):

**For NewRelic users:**

If you have integrated the newrelic jar in your app, this happens when the newrelic version is outOf date.

**Solution:**

Update the newrelic jar to the latest version. On eclipse, its just right click on the project and update newrelic. Or you can download the new version directly.

```
                                                                 Thanks amalBit
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and tried everything above but nothing helped me.

My projects are attached to GIT source control system, and I realized that there are some GIT related task while exporting to Andorid application. Then I commited all changes to the GIT repository and error dissapear.

So, if you are using GIT for source control and nothing above help you, try to commit all changes to the GIT repository (and eventually push to upstream) and try export again.