# Android Eclipse Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I have 2 projects I made.

The actual error:

Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/opencv/R$attr;

cameranoservice Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/opencv/R$attr;

One is using OpenCV as a library to do some image processing and is also used as a library for the second project.

The other one is just a test project to see if the first project can work as a library.

first project:

[image]

Second project:

[image]

I tried many things but at the end I just revert back all the changes because it breaks my project even more.

Comment: Give a try on(multiple occurrences of the same library also create this problem), http://stackoverflow.com/a/20017942/1537419

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted all the bin folders, then ran Clean and then Build. Restarted Eclipse. Unchecked the contents of Android Private Libraries and checked Android Private Libraries of each project. This solved the issue. This solution was mentioned in a related post on stack overflow though it was one of many

Comment: I actually deleted all bin folders (even if I thought it was insane first), build then restarted. I didn't touch the private libraries though I just unchecked the openCV one in fdm project (android dependencies). And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler found the duplicate of this jar- "Opencv library-2.4.11.jar". You try to check is it this .jar also was call on Android Privates Libraries. If so, then remove this .jar from the Android Dependencies Libraries.